# Python: Why can't I use plot for the last rows of a dataframe when calling it with .tail() method, but when using iloc to define the rows it works?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a df with columns of weeks and different stores' sales
When I try to plot a the sum of sales for the last month using .tail() and sum(), it gives me a Type error:

df.tail(16).sum().plot(kind='bar')

TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot[image]
[image]
But, if I used iloc,
df.iloc[:-16, 1:].sum().plot(kind='bar');

It works

Why is this happening? what is the difference here in calling with the 2 methods?

Thanks

Comment: note that `df.tail(16)` is not the same as `df.iloc[:-16, :]` (should be `df.iloc[-16:, :]`)

Comment: please edit the post to include the output of `df.tail(16)`

Comment: @tdy I added the output for tail(16)
Please explain why df.tail(16) is not the same as df.iloc[:-16, :]

Comment: i meant post the output of `df.tail(16)`, not the whole plotting command

Comment: `:-16` means everything up to index `-16`, but `tail(16)` means index `-16` to the end, which is `-16:`

Comment: Yes, sorry I meant df.iloc[-16:, :], it gives the same data range as df.tail(16) but gives error when trying to plot tail(16) only

Comment: We need to see the output of `df.tail(16)` (not the plotting output, just the actual contents of `df.tail(16)`). We can't tell what's happening without seeing the concrete data.